# Qual é a tradução de bullet points?

Tags: tradução-inglês

No internetês, *bullet points* seriam

- esses pontos
- que indicam
- listas

No português, como chamamos esses pontos? Qual seria uma boa tradução?

Comment: Parece que se diz bullets mesmo. pequeno círculo preto, pelo menos no Brasil.

Comment: @Lambie Realmente, no Brasil eu ouço _bullets_, mas temos aqui a tradição de usar palavras no Inglês mesmo, sem traduzi-las como em Portugal.

Comment: Marcas ou Numeração

Comment: @gmauch Sim, eu sei. Acho que acaba sendo indiretamente o fruto da ditadura militar. Os intelectuais fugiram do pais. :)

Comment: As pessoas que mais provavelmente usam *bullets* são os usuários de editores de texto e outros programas com interface em inglês: é mais fácil usar a palavra escrita na tua frente do que lembrar da tradução. Suponho que seja assim, e via teclados com a palavra *delete*, que o verbo "deletar" tenha sido introduzido no nosso vocabulário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [dicionário](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-portuguese/bullet-point) da Cambridge e também a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_lista) chamam esse marcador de "ponto lista". No dia a dia eles costumam ser chamados simplesmente "pontos" ou, genericamente, de "marcadores" (cf. e.g. a [documentação](https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/pt-br/GS50/PDF/GS5004-Introducao-ao-Writer-ptbr.pdf) do Write do LibreOffice), ou ainda pelo termo em inglês.

Já os itens em si de uma dessas listas (também chamados de *bullet points*) podem ser chamados por nomes como "pontos principais" e similares.

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria apenas "pontos". Se o contexto for claro, é suficiente.